# Unable to copy PDF file using FileInputStream

Tags: java, file, pdf, fileoutputstream, bufferedoutputstream

I am trying to copy a PDF file from 1 location to another, but once I run the following code, I am unable to open the PDF (it is showing the following error.)

> There was an error opening this document. The file is damaged and
>   could not be repaired

```
public class BinaryFileTransfer {

    private static String INPUT_FILE = "C:\\Users\\sashwat\\Desktop\\a.pdf";
    private static String OUTPUT_FILE = "C:\\Users\\sashwat\\Desktop\\a-copy.pdf";

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(INPUT_FILE));

        OutputStream wos = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(OUTPUT_FILE));

        int len = 0;
        byte[] brr = new byte[1000];
        while ((len = is.read(brr)) != -1) {
            wos.write(brr, 0, len);
        }
    }
}
```

Can someone help me as to what exactly am I doing wrong?

Comment: The files are the same size, once the copy is finished?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that you're not closing the input / output streams. This is a resource leak and I reproduced your problem on a Windows machine.

Starting with Java 7, you can use the [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) statement to do that automatically:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    try (InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(INPUT_FILE));
        OutputStream wos = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(OUTPUT_FILE))) {
        int len = 0;
        byte[] brr = new byte[1000];
        while ((len = is.read(brr)) != -1) {
            wos.write(brr, 0, len);
        }
    }
}
```

At the end of the try part, each resource opened will be closed.

However, I strongly suggest that you start using the [Java NIO.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/fileio.html) API. You can copy a file directly with [`Files.copy`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#copy-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.CopyOption...-).

```
Files.copy(Paths.get(INPUT_FILE), Paths.get(OUTPUT_FILE));
```

It can also take a 3rd argument that are [`CopyOption`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/CopyOption.html). An example could be [`StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/StandardCopyOption.html#REPLACE_EXISTING) which replaces the target file if it already exists.